# Audio recording is stopped when application goes to background

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

I am using "AudioRecord" class to record the voice in my application. Everything works fine but when the application goes to background the recording is getting stopped. 
I tried to start the recording in a separate thread also. But no use.
How can I resolve this issue? Any Idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that extends `Service` and insert your AudioRecord code there. Hope it helps.

Comment: More precisely you should use ForeGround services : ShowNotification() + return START_STICKY + StartForegoundService()